# Prevent `document.execCommand("copy")` from replacing ampersands

Tags: javascript, jquery, segment-io

I have a tool which generates URLs, and a button for copying the generated URL to the clipboard. This function does successfully copy my URL:

```
function copyUrlToClipboard() {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val(myUrl).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}
```

However, in the copied URL, ampersand characters are replaced with `&amp%3B`. For example, the url

`mysite.com/?utm_source=se&utm_medium=foo`

becomes

`mysite.com/?utm_source=se&amp%3Butm_medium=foo`

Unfortunately I use segment/amplitude analytics downstream, which fails to extract parameters from this URL.

Why does this happen? Is there a way to change the behaviour of `copy`, or some post-processing I can do on the clipboard item? Failing that, does anybody know if segment can be configured to be smarter about parameter extraction?

**Update**:

Upon investigation it appears that `$temp.val()` is responsible for replacing `&` with `&amp;` (I'm not sure what the term for this is - sanitizing it?) and then upon pasting the url in the browser the `;` is sanitized as `%3B`. But I don't understand why `val()` is being sanitized, is there a property/attribute I can set on my temp element, or a different type of element to use?

Comment: Maybe `$temp.value`?

Comment: Provide a runnable demo that reproduces issue that others can test against as per [mcve]. You can make it runnable here in the page by clicking on **`<>`** in question editor

Comment: Where does `myUrl` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to comment suggestions. It was because `myUrl` was coming from a django template variable:

`{{ original.my_url }}`

As it turns out I had to mark this variable as [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/language/#string-literals-and-automatic-escaping):

`{{ original.my_url | safe }}`

This now copies the url without modification. Thank you for the suggestions!